# (Multithreading-Python) How I can create a script that run two scripts which I usually run from two different terminals?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I have two scripts `a.py` and `b.py`, they send data to each other via a local host (mqtt), and they both depend from a configuration file `conf.jso`n. I usually execute them in two different terminals,

- a.py in one terminal
- b.py in another

and everything it's OK. I am trying right now to create another script `c.py` which should do the following:

- for parameter in parameters
- update `config.json`
- execute `a.py` and `b.py` "in two different terminals"
- close `a.py`, `b.py` and start again with the new parameters

Now, I am very noob about this, so I tried to use Thread from threading

```
from threading import Thread

for parameter in parameter 
    #update config.json
    class exp(Thread):
        def __init__(self, name):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.name = name
        def run(self):
            if self.name == 0:
               a.runs()
            else:
               b.runs()
    thread1 = exp(0)
    thread1.start()
    thread2 = exp(1)
    thread2.start()
```

a.py and b.py scripts both end by:

```
def runs():
    #whatever runs do
if __name__ = 'main':
   runs()
```

It runs without errors, but it does not work. I am quite sure there should be a nice and standard solution to this problem. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `multiprocessing`, not the `threading` library (look up `multiprocessing.Process`. Another fairly equivalent option is to use `subprocess.run` to launch the two scripts via shell.

Regarding threads - Keep in mind they are limited due to the Global Interpreter Lock in `CPython` - which is the prevalent python implementation and the one you probably are using.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try today and send updates.

Comment: So I tried to call the two scripts with subprocess.Popen, but still I do not get the right result. I think there is some sync problem. a.py should send an output to b.py which runs and then send an output to a.py etc etc...but for some reason this process seems to be compromise, meanwhile there is no problem if I run the two scripts in two different terminals.

Comment: Moreover, is there a way to show the output of the two scripts in two different terminals?

Comment: You can capture the output either by redirection or in a finished process return value. Not sure what you mean by "send an output to" - to have processes communicate with each other you generally want to use some form of IPC, depending on your use case. As far as I saw you didn't mention it in the OP - you should update it there if this is indeed the case and it is imperative for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually found this (dirty) solution...any advices for improvements?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'random.py']) #initialize a random process just to make sense of the firsts terminate calls in the for cycle. 
for parameter in parameters
    subprocess.Popen.terminate(p)
    #random code
     p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'a.py'])
     p = subprocess.call(['python', 'b.py'])
    #here I would like to do
    #subprocess.Popen.terminate(p)....but it does not work, so I putted the terminate process at the start of the for cycle
```

I do not totally understand what I wrote but it works fine. Thanks everybody for previous tips, and I hope for further explanations.

Comment: Thanks for updating your solution. You should mark it as accepted, such that it appears first for subsequent users. 

According to documentation the new interface is subprocess.run, not subprocess.call as I wrote earlier - prefer it over Popen. No reason to intermix run and Popen. There's no reason to Popen and terminate a process. 

You might want to use shell=True.

Comment: Note that calling processes is a very standard and well-working functionality. So any bugs or dirty solutions are generally due to your poor usage of the API... you can try to detail *in your original post* what you need  in terms of communication between the processes to maybe have a cleaner solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can us qt Threading. Qt has a very powerful library exactly for this purpose.

Comment: downvote because failed to mention there are immediate options in the standard library.

Comment: I'll keep in mind, but I prefer standard solutions when they are available. Thanks!